# MySqlException: Access denied for user 'altjenb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine

I dont know why am I getting this, user, altjenb has full access in the mysql db but I still keep getting the same error. I tried to use online db at mysql8.db4free.net and db4free.net and got the same error. tried in localhost (xampp) and still the same error..

> MySqlException: Access denied for user 'altjenb'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

this is the connection string

```
MySqlConnection connectionstring = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; port= 3306; Database=battlehunt_db; UserId=altjenb; Password=egrgeaf;");
```

I manually granted full access to the user. but still nothing, 
I tried to give access with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * battlehunt_db. * TO 'altjenb'@'localhost';
```

but still is the same error.

but when I change the userID to root and no password. it connects to the db.. it looks like it doesnt receive the user name.. I tried to add a random user name who is not registered in (eg. egwetr) and still it showed the same error..

how can I fix this?

Im trying to connect unity3d 5 with mysql db

Comment: My first thought is to check the password,

Comment: I've done it. many times.

Comment: Try resetting the password for `altjenb` on the database so you are absolutely positive you are using the correct password

Comment: In the user table the field Host of that user do you have 'localhost' or '%'? For Mysql 'localhost' it's not the same as '127.0.0.1'

Comment: @PabloMartinez can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can I do that? I cant find anything on google which tell me how to reset the pasword for a specific account. all they say is for root

Comment: Ooo I dont know, maybe [look in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) and `SET PASSWORD FOR 'altjenb'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('Your_new_password');`

Comment: Can you access to the database with that user in CLI?

Comment: @RiggsFolly seems that your solution worked. but how can I do this online at a host like mysql8.db4free.net? I dont have admin privileges to do it.

Comment: You ask the hosting company what the user account and password is for your database. Or you look in the hosts documentation. There is normally a way to set/reset the password.via the admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Explaining my comment on the question.

Assuming that the password for that user is correct the Error message:

```
MySqlException: Access denied for user 'altjenb'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It can mean that the user does not have permision to connect to the server 'localhost'

In the user table you can see to what host has permission:

```
---------------------------
   user     |    host     |
---------------------------
user1       |   localhost |
user1       |   127.0.0.1 |
user2       |   127.0.0.1 |
```

in this example, user1 can connect to localhost and 127.0.0.1 so:

```
new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; port= 3306; Database=battlehunt_db; UserId=user1; Password=egrgeaf;");
new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; port= 3306; Database=battlehunt_db; UserId=user1; Password=whatever;");
```

both connections will work

But user 2 only has access to 127.0.0.1

so:

```
new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; port= 3306; Database=battlehunt_db; UserId=user2; Password=egrgeaf;");
```

will fail because it's trying to connect to 'localhost'

and

```
new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; port= 3306; Database=battlehunt_db; UserId=user2; Password=whatever;");
```

will succeed.

Check in the user table of Mysql to what host has access the user 'altjenb', if 'altjenb' does not have the host 'localhost' you can add it or change the connection string to one of the hosts the user has.

hope this help

Comment: I fixed the localserver by changing the password. but what about the server online of mysql8.db4free.net or db4free.net

Comment: I haven't worked with db4free, but you should have somewhere (email, webadministration,...) what server to use

Comment: was talking with the admin and we figured out the solution. it could connect to db4free.net but couldnt to mysql8.db4free.net. the connector wasnt updated and couldnt make the connection

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the code. but with the connector, the version of connector I use is not updated with mysql8.