# "Access Denied" error while trying to open PHP site with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I've got a complete cPanel backup of an old website I inherited, built with CodeIgniter. I am trying to open the `index.php` file with `MAMP`.

When I try to open it by visiting **localhost:8888/index.php**, I get this error message:

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'theuscs_us'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Does this mean that the site is password locked? Is there any other way I can view the site in my browser? I'm totally new to MAMP, PHP, and CMS generally, so any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it's failing on the database connection.  Have you created the corresponding database and user?

Comment: most back ups dont include user creation, so check if ''theuscs_us' exists

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609572/mysqlexception-access-denied-for-user-altjenblocalhost-using-password-ye